# What is the default request method type for the request mapping?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

What is the default request method type for the `@RequestMapping`?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "addGoal")
public String addGoal(Model model) {...}
```

Comment: The default is none, as indicated by the javadoc. You narrow the mapping by adding one or several methods (also indicated by the javadoc).

Comment: so that means no request will be processed? what is completely wrong. it is or get or post or both of them...

Comment: No. You **narrow** the mapping by specifying methods. And there is also PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, TRACE

Comment: in the above example if `get` requested then will the method be executed?  what if it's `post` - will the method be executed? or every type is suitable for the above method?

Comment: If no method is specified, authomatically spring will create many endpoints as methods exists. In other words, you will have a head,post, put, get... from same endpoint.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you do not specify any mapping this method will resolve all the HTTP requests i.e. you can send GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, TRACE requests to the specified URL and it will be resolved, because it is used to narrow it down (no narrowing = all available).

See [official Spring-Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.1.2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html).

Comment: Codecademy [says](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-spring-fundamentals-and-controllers/lessons/responding-to-requests-with-spring/exercises/mapping-requests-in-spring) it defaults to GET

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Codeacademy is wrong on this one. See the official Spring-Boot documentation.