# Spring Conversion Magic

Tags: java, spring

I am having a piece of code like below for calling one of our service.

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> parametersMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            parametersMap.add("query", query);
            parametersMap.add("locale", "en_US");
            parametersMap.add("resultsLimit", Boolean.FALSE.toString());
            parametersMap.add("maxResults", maxResults);
            parametersMap.add("type", "TTT");
            parametersMap.add("ids", commaSeparatedValues(ids));
            parametersMap.add("infoTypes", "HHH,JJJ");
            HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(parametersMap, getHttpHeaders());
            MyEntity myEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://example.com", httpEntity, MyEntity.class);
```

And at the server side the controller code is like

```
    @RequestMapping("my/service")
                public MyEntity suggest(@RequestParam(required = true) String query, @RequestParam(required = true) String locale,
@RequestParam(required = false) String resultsLimit, @Valid OtherOptions options)
```

and the OtherOption class is like

```
class OtherOptions {
              String maxResults;
              String type;
              String ids;
              String infoTypes;
            }
```

Here everything is working fine, but I am confused about somethings like .

1. Is it a get or post request ?
2. How is some of the parameter maps content become request params(query params) and some others  got mapped to the Object of OtherOptions ?
3. Which is the actual body of the request ?

Comment: It's a GET request, the mapping is by method parameter variable/POJO field name, and the response should be JSON.

Comment: but you can see in the client code , we are using a resttemplate.post and as per the doc 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811606/what-is-the-default-request-method-type-for-the-request-mapping
requestmapping can be converted in to any thing right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is it a get or post request ?

   > It is a post request. you are calling `restTemplate.postForEntity`. But your server side method is not restricted as you didn't specify the `method` attribute for `RequestMapping` so same method can handle any http method from the point of server.
2. How is some of the parameter maps content become request params(query params) and some others got mapped to the Object of OtherOptions?

   > None of them are query params. 
   >   See the spring docs for the meaning of `@RequestParam`. In your case, it all comes from body and not as query params
   >
   > https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html
   >
   > https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForEntity-java.net.URI-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-
   >
   > The body of the entity, or request itself, can be a MultiValueMap to create a multipart request.
3. Which is the actual body of the request?

   > parametersMap is the body of the http request.

Note:
Currently your call should fail because you are posting it to `http://example.com` at client and listening at server side on `my/service`

Comment: The 3rd question was a typo, I meant in the request. Edited the question now.
Also how is the values in the map is getting converted to OtherOptions ?

Comment: see here how some of your RequestParams were used to create the OtherOptions object. http://dolszewski.com/spring/how-to-bind-requestparam-to-object/